# Apache Setting up multiple domains with http & https

Tags: php, linux, apache, ubuntu

I've been trying to add a second domain to my apache ubuntu server. I'm not getting any errors, but when I go to "test.ca" it still redirects to "example.com". What am I missing?? I want both domains on one server going to their own folders.

[How To Set Up Apache Virtual Hosts on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts)

[How To Set Up Apache Virtual Hosts on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts)

[How do I set up apache with multiple sites?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137267/how-do-i-set-up-apache-with-multiple-sites/137494)

[Hosting multiple websites with Apache2](https://www.debian-administration.org/article/412/Hosting_multiple_websites_with_Apache2)

Test.ca error log is empty.

Tounder.com error log is empty.

Apache error log is empty.

Permissions under `/var/`:

```
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root   4096 Dec 15 20:49 www
```

Permissions under `/var/www/html/`:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 11510 Dec 15 20:49 index.html
drwxr-xr-x 4 sys  sys   4096 Jan 11 19:19 test.ca
drwxr-xr-x 4 sys  sys   4096 Dec 15 21:00 example.com
```

`/etc/apache2/ports.conf`:

```
Listen 80

<IfModule ssl_module>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

The `/etc/hosts`:

```
myip servername
myip test.ca
myip example.com
```

The `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` is empty.

The `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-test.ca.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin test@gmail.com
    ServerName test.ca
    ServerAlias www.test.ca
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/test.ca/public_html/
    ErrorLog /var/www/html/test.ca/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/html/test.ca/logs/access.log combined
    <Directory /var/www/html/test.ca/>
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-example.com.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/localcerts/example.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/localcerts/example.com.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/localcerts/intermediate.crt

    ServerAdmin example@gmail.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example.com/public_html/
    ErrorLog /var/www/html/example.com/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/html/example.com/logs/access.log combined
    <Directory /var/www/html/example.com/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride all
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is for programming related questions. From the SO help: "Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com)".

Answer (score 0):

You might need to make the sites enabled.

If you go to **/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/** is there anything in there?

Try

```
$   sudo a2ensite 000-test.ca.conf
```

Comment: Did you restart apache after completing this step?

Comment: Yes I did restart the apache

Answer (score 0):

Check the following list to make sure your virtual host is configured correct:

1) In `sudo nano /etc/hosts` have your virtual host domain name. Here `111.111.111.111 test.ca`

2) Create `sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/test.ca.conf` . Don't prefix the file with '000-'.
File content:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@test.ca
    ServerName test.ca
    ServerAlias www.test.ca
    DocumentRoot /var/www/test.ca/public_html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

3) Run the command to enable test.ca `sudo a2ensite test.com.conf`

4) Finally restart apache `sudo service apache2 restart`

Now you will be able to load test.ca in your browser.